# Comparing two structs in Swift

Tags: swift

Consider a struct with a name two Int values :

```
struct StructWithNameAndTwoInts {
    let name: String
    let from: Int
    let to: Int
}
```

Now I want to compare two structs based on the values of `from` and `to`. There are three possibilities:

> Not equal: `from` and `to` from both structs are different.
>
> Half equal: Both `from`s are equal, but both `to`s are not.
>
> Equal: Both `from`s are equal and both `to`s are equal.

I also need to take into consideration the from and to could be swapped, so I cannot just use `A == B`. I came up with the following:

The three results could be in an enum:

```
enum CompareResult {
   case equal
   case halfEqual
   case notEqual
}
```

Then I could write a function for `StructWithTwoInts` to do the comparison:

```
func compareWith(_ other: StructWithTwoInts) -> CompareResult {
     if (self.from == other.from && self.to == other.to) || (self.from == other.to && self.to == other.from) {
        return .equal
     }
     else if (self.from == other.from && self.to != other.to) || (self.from == other.to && self.to != other.from) {
        return .halfEqual
     }
     else if (self.from != other.from && self.to != other.to) || (self.from != other.to && self.to != other.from) {
        return .notEqual
     }
}
```

And finally:

```
let A = StructWithNameAndTwoInts(name: "Foo", from: 5, to: 28)
let B = StructWithNameAndTwoInts(name: "Bar", from: 5, to: 22)
let C = StructWithNameAndTwoInts(name: "Baz", from: 2, to: 22)
let D = StructWithNameAndTwoInts(name: "Drop", from: 28, to: 5)

let result1 = A.compareWith(B)  // .halfEqual
let result2 = A.compareWith(C)  // .notEqual
let result3 = A.compareWith(D)  // .equal
```

This worked, but feels like a kludge. Is there anyway to write this differently?

Comment: Hold up why would the to and from be different but still be equal? That defies the statement in your post itself/

Comment: Also, please provide full context - did we even need to know this name property exists? If you mention it, you should include it.

Comment: So if A = (3, 24) and B = (24, 3) they should be equal.

Comment: I left the name out because I am not comparing the names in this particular case, only the from and to.

Comment: But they aren't! If two things are moving towards each other, that does not put them at the same position. And if you are not including the name or other properties, don't tell us that they exist.

Comment: That would indeed be the case if they were coordinates, but they are not in this case.

Comment: Your structure has poor naming. Is it really just a MyStruct? Or is there a name that would be helpful?

Comment: The name of the struct is completely irrelevant. Could you please focus your comments on the question?

Comment: My review on your question is of the only actual code you have here, and that is in the first block. My primary complaint is that there are poor naming conventions, you are telling us that there is additional info that is irrelevant, and if it truly is, we don't need to know it exists. So either put it in the code or do not.

Comment: Fine, I will update the question so you can focus on the review of the three lines.

Comment: _**My primary complaint is that there are poor naming conventions**_: Calling it a "StructWithTwoInts" is no more useful than calling it "MyStruct". Still just as useless, and no more meaningful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104463/discussion-between-freezephoenix-and-koen).

Comment: The close reason is misleading - I put the final close vote in because the code submitted for review cannot possibly compile, which makes it non-working code by definition. Feel free to address the review points from [the answer below](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237310/23788) and then post the updated code as a new, well-formed question with actual working code. See [how to post a follow-up question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/23788) on meta for all the details.

Comment: Fair enough about closing the question. Just for the record, I edited the question after the (in my opinion) irrelevant comments about lack of context and misleading struct naming. The edited code was entered in the browser without testing in Xcode. The answer below has a lot of useful suggestions so I will leave it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. Your `compareWith(_:)` will not compile, as you have a path of execution where you are not returning any value.
2. We’ve also moved away from method names with the trailing preposition, and might name it `compare(with:)` instead. Or because you're not considering the name associated with these pairs of numbers, I might call it `compareValues(with:)` to make it unambiguous that we’re ignoring the name associated with this pair, and only comparing their respective values.
3. I might suggest giving this structure a more meaningful name. In the absence of more information, I'll just call it a `NamedPair`.

   ```
   struct NamedPair {
       let name: String
       let from: Int
       let to: Int
   }
   ```

   That having been said, I'd probably rename `from` and `to` as well because that suggests some directionality which may or may not be valid. (I also wouldn't generally use a preposition, alone, for a property name, probably leaning towards `fromValue` and `toValue` at the very least.) But as you haven't shared the functional intent for this structure, I've left those property names alone.
4. I might be inclined to use tuples for the equality state and separate out the “reversed” scenario into its own test, to make the intent absolutely explicit and clear.

   I also think you're missing the “half equal” scenario where `self.to == other.from`.

   Anyway, pulling that together, perhaps something:

   ```
   extension NamedPair {
       enum CompareResult {
          case equal
          case halfEqual
          case notEqual
       }

       func compareValues(with other: NamedPair) -> CompareResult {
           if (from, to) == (other.from, other.to) {
               return .equal
           } else if (from, to) == (other.to, other.from) {
               return .equal
           } else if from == other.from || from == other.to || to == other.to || to == other.from {
               return .halfEqual
           } else {
               return .notEqual
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. While I've called this `NamedPair`, it strikes me that this might be, more generally, a `NamedSet`, where you might just want to know whether the sets match, intersect, or are disjoint:

   ```
   struct NamedSet {
       let name: String
       let set: Set<Int>
   }

   extension NamedSet {
       enum CompareResult {
          case equal
          case intersect
          case disjoint
       }

       func compareValues(with other: NamedSet) -> CompareResult {
           if set == other.set {
               return .equal 
           } else if set.isDisjoint(with: other.set) {
               return .disjoint
           } else {
               return .intersect
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Not only does this handle the generalized scenario, but it offloads the equality and intersection logic to the existing `Set` type.
6. For what it’s worth, these are both seem like good candidates to be generics:

   ```
   struct NamedPair<T: Comparable> {
       let name: String
       let from: T
       let to: T
   }

   extension NamedPair {
       enum CompareResult {
          case equal
          case halfEqual
          case notEqual
       }

       func compareValues(with other: NamedPair) -> CompareResult {
           if (from, to) == (other.from, other.to) {
               return .equal
           } else if (from, to) == (other.to, other.from) {
               return .equal
           } else if from == other.from || from == other.to || to == other.to || to == other.from {
               return .halfEqual
           } else {
               return .notEqual
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   And

   ```
   struct NamedSet<T: Hashable> {
       let name: String
       let set: Set<T>
   }

   extension NamedSet {
       enum CompareResult {
          case equal
          case intersect
          case disjoint
       }

       func compareValues(with other: NamedSet) -> CompareResult {
           if set == other.set {
               return .equal 
           } else if set.isDisjoint(with: other.set) {
               return .disjoint
           } else {
               return .intersect
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Ah, using a Set makes a lot of sense. I'll go over all your comments this weekend.